# problem in loading excel file using oracle odi to table

Tags: excel, oracle, oracle-data-integrator, jdbc-odbc

I want to import many excel files (XLSX) to tables using oracle ODI according to instructions in [here](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&source=web&rct=j&opi=89978449&url=https://blogs.oracle.com/dataintegration/post/how-to-load-data-from-excel-using-odi-1221-and-progress-datadirect-sequelink&ved=2ahUKEwjxp9WI7o-FAxXF8QIHHXPVBLAQFnoECCIQAQ&usg=AOvVaw0H97adVMMKs9jUk5C4WaXK) I need a JDBC – ODBC BRIDGE DRIVER to load data (because java 8 don't support this driver internally) but I can't find any free and open source driver to do it.

My question is are there any free driver for this reason or if not are there other solution for this problem.